# How can I use NOT BETWEEN in a query in Phalcon?

Tags: phalcon

I am making a query using NOT BETWEEN using Phalcon Query Language (PHQL), but it is not working the application hangs.
Someone could give me an idea of ​​how I could do it. Thank you very much.
There is my query.

```
       $sql = "SELECT c.* FROM table as c 
      WHERE not exists c.activated NOT BETWEEN :f1: and :f2: ";
        $parameters['f1'] = '2017-10-01';
        $parameters['f2'] = '2017-10-05';
        $result= $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($sql, 
        $parameters);
```

every time the query is run this leaves:

> Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\plugins\SecurityPlugin.php on line 222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of Phalcon Query Language (PHQL) until I opened this question, but the syntax you are attempting isn't valid in SQL. Try this instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.* FROM table as c WHERE NOT c.activated BETWEEN :f1: and :f2: ";
    $parameters['f1'] = '2017-10-01';
    $parameters['f2'] = '2017-10-05';
    $result= $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($sql, 
    $parameters);
```

**NOT** ( *your_predicate_here* )

All you need is the NOT to reverse the true/false values being returned by the predicate. e.g. if a date IS between the dates (true), reverse that to false so it is equivalent to "not between".

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3bb3b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`activated` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`activated`)
VALUES
    ('2016-12-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-10-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-10-05 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM table1 as c 
WHERE NOT c.activated BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-05'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3bb3b/1/0)**:

```
|            activated |
|----------------------|
| 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: really works brother, thanks for the good explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wonderful please I could be of assistance . Do you know how to "Accept" the answer?  This indicstes to other readers that there is a solution.